# How do I know GPU usage on Android devices?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gpu

I know that the CPU statistics are stored in "/sys/devices/system/cpu" and use them.

But I could never find where the GPU usage was.

I spent more than 300 hours on this, but I couldn't find a cool answer anywhere but I heard only meaningless answers.

My question is, I want to know where GPU utilization is, just like CPU data is stacked on a particular file. Or is there an ADB command? Somebody help me, please.

What I'm looking for is not "Tool" but how to get data programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it's device dependant. E.g. for Mali GPU it's in dir: /sys/class/misc/mali0/device/utilization Qualcomm devices dir: /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/ /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/max_gpuclk /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpuclk

Comment: Thank you! Can you look at this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112025/how-to-access-files-without-rooting-on-an-android-device

Comment: Glad that I could help you! I will look into your next question.