# How to access files without rooting on an Android device

Tags: android

I try to read the file using adb. However, "Permission Denied" is printed and Permission is "lrwxrwxrwx".

Question 1:
How can I read this file without rooting?

Question 2: 
What does "l" mean in "lrwxrwxrwx"?

Comment: upload your adb command to read the file.

Answer (score 2):

The first letter is simply the type of file.
This letter will be one of following three.

```
  l for a link to another file, 
  d for a directory 
  - for a file and is set by the linux operating system
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do a `cat`: `adb shell cat /sdcard/D_Permission/foo.txt`
2. lrwxrwxrwx can be read as, **L**ink (**R**ead, **W**rite, **E**xecute)*3.