# How to retrieve GPU utilization or similar GPU metrics on Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, gpu

I have problem retrieving GPU utilization or similar GPU metrics. Is there a way of reading this data from application code?

I tried looking for specific files from this answer ([How do I know GPU usage on Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077963/how-do-i-know-gpu-usage-on-android-devices)), but I can't seem to find these files.

I would like to read GPU metrics in Android app's code.